# How to reduce memory load with pandas json_read chunksize argument?

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance, memory

I have a list of very large json files (around a hundred files, each with hundreds of thousands of records) that I would like to read using the chunksize argument in pandas.read_json in order to reduce the memory load. However, it doesn't appear to be reducing the memory load, so I must be doing something wrong. Here's what I have:

```
keys = ['created_at','id','full_text','retweet_count','favorite_count','entities','user']
user_keys = ['screen_name','id','location','followers_count','created_at','statuses_count']
tweets = pd.DataFrame(columns = keys)
tweets_user = pd.DataFrame(columns = user_keys)

# pull relevant information, save to df
for file in filelist:
    j = pd.read_json(file, lines = True, chunksize = 1000)
    for chunk in j:
        tweets_temp = pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns = keys)
        tweets = tweets.append(tweets_temp,ignore_index = True)
        tweets_user = tweets_user.append(pd.DataFrame(tweets_temp['user'].to_list(), columns = user_keys), ignore_index = True)
```

In addition, although I'm aware that the chunk size argument slows the process down, it is now so slow that it would take over a week to read all of the files, which isn't feasible for me. Is there anything I can do to optimize speed here while also keeping the memory load under control?